# Custom authorization in ADO.NET Data Services

Tags: security, ado.net, authorization, wcf-data-services

I have an ADO.NET Data Service that exposes an Entity Framework data model (.edmx).

I need to allow / reject reads/writes to certain entities for certain users. I use Windows Authentication. All I could find is overriding the OnStartProcessingRequest :

```
protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
{
    base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);

    bool isBatch = args.IsBatchOperation;
    System.Uri requestUri = args.RequestUri;

    // parse uri and determine the entity and the operation
    // (i.e.: select/update/delete/insert) will be determined by the HTTP verb
}
```

However I think this sucks and I am hoping for a better solution... Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the entity rights on service initialization for each user like

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Orders", UserRights.GetRights(identity, "Orders"));

config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Products", UserRights.GetRights(identity, "Products"));
```

The main disadvantages of applying resource visibility in this way are that the visibility is at entity level and not at row level.

You can overcome that with a combination of service operations and change interceptors.

```
[ChangeInterceptor("Products")]
public void OnProductsChange(Products product, UpdateOperations operations)
{
      if(!UserRights.HasAccessRights(identity, "Products", operations))
      {
             throw new DateServicesException(404, "Access denied!");
      }
}
```

Comment: the first example should be used if you dont want ppl to have specific access to the entire table/resource

the second example could be used in scenarios like a user cant create products that exceed a specific price margin that is dependant on some server side calculation.